# How I can run MessageBox.Show() from App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, messagebox

Can I run MessageBox.Show() from App.xaml.cs, so it is shown on current page. Please provide some code to this solution, or some other solution. I need to show some system message which is relevant for whole application.

Comment: MessageBox.Show() always shows on top of the current page. Can you explain your requirements a bit more, please?

Comment: It is true, when you run it from current page, but I need to run it by some event from  App.xaml.cs class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure, but would this not work?

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
 MessageBox.Show("");
}
);
```

You could also use the navigation data that is available in App.xaml.cs to determine the current Page and execute on that page.

I guess whatever you come up with, the app needs to be in a stable state, you probably can't do this when your handling (unhandled) exception. You should tell us a bit more so we understand why you want to do this. It seems that seomthing is wrong with your setup if you have to call MessageBox.Show from App.xaml.cs

Comment: This works for me, thanks. I need to notifier the user, when application is receive RAW PushNotification. User can be anywhere in application. User can disable this function in the setting if he don't like one.

Comment: There are different ways to approach that. The first thing i'm thinking of is creating an event which is triggered when the notification arrivess, so the Pages can subscribe to this. This way you can handle it from within the actual page instead from within App.xaml.cs. You could create a derived base class from Page which you will use for all your pages which implements a common method to handle the event. I hope this makes some sense. You should try to keep the App.xaml clean.

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach would be...

```
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    public static void ShowBox(string msg)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
  }
```

And then from a window, or any other part of your application...

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      App.ShowBox("Hello!");
      ...
```

Since the 'ShowBox' method is static, you can just call into it from anywhere.  Of course it goes without saying that this isn't really the 'cleanest' or most robust approach, but it will work.

Comment: Thanks, but my event is from App class, and MessageBox.Show(msg) should be show on top of any page.

Comment: It is my understanding that the messagebox will always be topmost, and therefore display on top of any page.

Comment: Yes, it is, now my question is, how i can run it from App class, not from any other page, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question is you are looking for a way to display message from App.xaml.cs when some event occurs else where in your application.

You can have **observer pattern** implemented with App.xaml.cs registered for an event which may be triggered by your custom page.

Having said that, in long run I suggest you to use **messaging framework** for this purpose. Most of the **MVVM frameworks** come with messaging framework. They are easy to use with no or little learning curve.

1. MVVM Light
2. Simple MVVM
3. PRISM from MS patterns & practices. (for larger applications) This is Not just an MVVM framework.
4. Ultra light MVVM

there are many more such frameworks.

Comment: Thanks, I need to triggered from App.xaml.cs

Answer (score 1):

I used this extract from this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c25b6d/message-dialog-in-windows-store-apps/

```
private async void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this record?");

        messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes", (command) =>
        {
            //Do delete
        }));
        messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No", (command) =>
        {
            //Do Nothing
        }));
        //default command
        messageDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 1;
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had no luck with the other solutions, found:

```
CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync
```

Works on windows phone 8.1 for calling a MessageDialog to ui thread from App.xaml.cs.